# functools.map alternative for dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, functools

### TL;DR

Iteration + in place modification for `dict` as with `functools.map` over `list`

### Abstract

As you might know, `list` objects can easily be processed in a single line by using `functools.map`, which takes a `lambda` and a `list` (or multiple) as parameters.
Problem is, I'd like to do the same for `dict` objects since what I currently have is:

```py
from functools import reduce

items = {
  'a': list(range(20)),
  'b': list(range(40)) 
}
power = lambda base, power: reduce(lambda a,b: a*b, [base for i in range(1,power)])
for key, value in items.items():
  items[key] = [power(i, 3) for i in value]
```

I don't really like this `for` as it currently is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

map does not actually do in place modification and it does the same thing as a list comprehension.

For a dictionary , you could do this:

```
items = { k:[power(i,3) for i in v] for k,v in items.items() }
```

Comment: That feels way better. Does it do an in place modification or there's momentarily a duplicate of the original `dict`object? I'm working with a lot of data.

Comment: map is an iterator.  To use its output you would need to build a new dictionary anyway.  That is alse what the dictionary comprehension in my answer does.  So there is no additional memory allocation outside of the output itself.